# Search for a place or address like in Apple Maps iOS 10

Tags: ios, mapkit, mklocalsearch

I am trying to recreate/get a same search list from MKLocalSearch but no luck. I tried many options with region, radius, delta. But my results different instead results from Apple Maps app. Result of apple maps is more better for all of idea for search places.

I used [MapSearch](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/MapSearch/Introduction/Intro.html) app for example from Apple documentation

and options

```
MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchString; 
request.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.userCoordinate.latitude, self.userCoordinate.longitude), 100, 100);
```

And its a big differents

[image]
[image]

**Update:**

I noticed when I put more precise queries, result is a same (if I put full name of place), but I don't have any idea how find more result use one letter like in example

Comment: have tried to increase your region ?  request.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.userCoordinate.latitude, self.userCoordinate.longitude), 2000, 2000); for example

Comment: @GIJOW, I tried but no luck

Comment: I think the search results in the right image come from the application logic of the Maps app, which knows your previous searches and many other things. I believe, that you have to implement similar functions to have similar results.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try MKLocalSearchCompleter API. Here is documentation link. https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mklocalsearchcompleter